# create subdomain in yii for particalur controller

Tags: php, yii, yii-components, yii-url-manager

I am looking for answer in **yii**.I want to create subdomain in yii.I want to do url rewrite like this.This should be applied to only one controller not every.

from

```
http://abcd.com/directory-1/directory-2/CotrollerName/FunctionName/Argument1/
```

to

```
http://Argument1.abcd.com/directory-1/directory-2/CotrollerName/FunctionName/
```

**Thanks in advance !!!**

Answer (score 0):

A tricky solution will look like:

```
class ControllerName extends Controller {

//...

public function FunctionName($Argument1 = NULL) {

    if ($Argument1 === NULL)
        $Argument1 = preg_filter('/^([^\.]+)\.abcd\.com$/', '$1', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);

    else
        $this->redirect("http://$Argument1.abc.com/.....");

    assert(!empty($Argument1));

 //.. more code here ...
}
```

Comment: Its not an good idea becuase i need to call this function explicitly

Comment: @BhattBhaskar can you elaborate? To apply the same solution to more functions you can create a helper or put the logic inside the base class constructor (Controller, MyController, etc)